# Create relationships after creating the nodes in py2neo

Tags: python, neo4j, py2neo

I am actually working on genetics currently trying to learn py2neo to make biological databases and i'm kinda newbie so excuse me for this easy question.

I have a codon dictionary that looks like this:

```
codon_dict={'A': ['GCT', 'GCC', 'GCA', 'GCG'], 'C': ['TGT', 'TGC'], 'E': ['GAA', 'GAG'], 'D': ['GAT', 'GAC'], 'G': ['GGT', 'GGC', 'GGA', 'GGG'], 'F': ['TTT', 'TTC'], 'I': ['ATT', 'ATC', 'ATA'], 'H': ['CAT', 'CAC'], 'K': ['AAA', 'AAG'], 'M': ['ATG'], 'L': ['CTT', 'CTC', 'TTA', 'CTA', 'TTG', 'CTG'], 'N': ['AAT', 'AAC'], 'Q': ['CAA', 'CAG'], 'P': ['CCT', 'CCC', 'CCA', 'CCG'], 'S': ['TCT', 'TCC', 'TCA', 'TCG', 'AGT', 'AGC'], 'R': ['CGT', 'CGC', 'CGA', 'AGA', 'CGG', 'AGG'], 'T': ['ACT', 'ACC', 'ACA', 'ACG'], 'W': ['TGG'], 'V': ['GTT', 'GTC', 'GTA', 'GTG'], 'Y': ['TAT', 'TAC'], 'Stop': ['TAA', 'TAG', 'TGA']}
```

And a simple code to create nodes:

```
from py2neo import neo4j
from py2neo import node,rel

gdb=neo4j.GraphDatabaseService()

gdb.clear()

for i in codon_dict:
    gdb.create(({"aminoacid_name":i,"comprised_of":codon_dict[i]}))
```

This gives me :

```
[Node('http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/9830')]
[Node('http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/9831')]
[Node('http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/9832')]
[Node('http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/9833')]
[Node('http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/9834')]
[Node('http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/9835')]
[Node('http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/9836')]
[Node('http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/9837')]
[Node('http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/9838')]
[Node('http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/9839')]
[Node('http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/9840')]
[Node('http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/9841')]
[Node('http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/9842')]
[Node('http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/9843')]
[Node('http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/9844')]
[Node('http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/9845')]
[Node('http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/9846')]
[Node('http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/9847')]
[Node('http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/9848')]
[Node('http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/9849')]
[Node('http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/9850')]
```

After this code i get all the nodes i want but i can't assign relationships to them via their names or urls after creating the nodes( (A,"is similar",V) or (9850,"STOPS",9840) ).

Is there a way to create relationships seperately after i create the nodes or must i relate them to eachother while creating them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mehmet,

Here's [a link](http://nigelsmall.com/py2neo/1.6/graphs_nodes_relationships/#nodes-relationships) that shows you what you need.

The return value from each create call is a Node object for the node just created, so you could store those in separate variables or a dictionary and use them to build relationships. You can also get each node back from the database if you use the neo4j.Node(uri) syntax shown in the link above. The arguments in the create method to build the relationship must be Node objects or 0-based index references to nodes created within the same create method call. You won't be using the index form, so you would have something like

```
codon_nodes = dict()

for i in codon_dict:
    codon_nodes[i] = gdb.create(({"aminoacid_name":i,"comprised_of":codon_dict[i]}))[0]

rel = gdb.create((codon_nodes['A'], 'is similar', codon_nodes['V']))
```

Grace and peace,

Jim

Comment: This is not quite correct. The `create` method returns a list of objects, even when only one is being created. This means that the return value needs to be unpacked in this instance by using a trailing comma after `codon_nodes[i]`. See the warning about this here -> http://nigelsmall.com/py2neo/1.6/graphs_nodes_relationships/#py2neo.neo4j.GraphDatabaseService.create

Comment: Yes but i just added few to make it right (rel = gdb.create((codon_nodes['A'][0], 'is similar', codon_nodes['V'][0])))
Thank you both.

Comment: By the way py2neo rocks! Keep it up please :)